# How should I construct $\color{Green}{\text{explicitly}}$ the associated torus to the general quadratic field $ \mathbb{Q} \sqrt d $?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

In the **introduction** of the article 
**An elliptic curve test for Mersenne primes** by **Benedict H. Gross**, 
it is only mentioned that:

$T$ is the one-dimensional algebraic torus $T$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, 
associated to the real quadratic 
field $ k= \mathbb{Q} \sqrt3 $ .

1. **First question**: Could you explain $T$ for me in more details or 
   could you construct it for me $\color{Red}{\text{explicitly}}$?

---

---

If $l \geq 3 $ is a prime, 
and $p = 2^l − 1$ is the corresponding Mersenne number, 
then 
$$    p \overset {24} {\equiv}  7         .$$ 
$$ %% p                  {≡}    7 (mod 24).$$

Let $ A = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt3 $ 
be the ring of integers, 
of discriminant $12$, 
inside the real quadratic field $k = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt3)$. 
Let $\sigma$ be the non-trivial automorphism of $k$, 
for which $\sigma(\sqrt3)=-\sqrt3$. 
The ring $A$ has class number $1$ and fundamental unit 
$$\varepsilon=2+\sqrt3 \ .$$
The unit $\varepsilon$ is totally positive
and satisfies $\varepsilon . \varepsilon^{\sigma}=1$. 
**It ($\varepsilon$) provides an integral point 
on the algebraic torus $T$ mentioned in the introduction.**

Let $q$ be a prime number, 
and let $T(q)$ be the subgroup of $(A/q)^*$ 
consisting of elements of norm $1$ to $(Z/q)^*$. 
By reduction (mod $q$), 
we may consider $\varepsilon$ as an element 
of the finite group $T(q)$.

2. **Second question**: Why the norm map from 
   $(A/q)^*$ to $(Z/q)^*$ is **surjective**?
3. **Third question**: What does it mean by:
   **It ($\varepsilon$) provides an integral point 
   on the algebraic torus $T$ mentioned in the introduction.**

---

---

4. **Fourth question**: This question is the natural generalization of the **First question**. 
   How should I construct $\color{Blue}{\text{explicitly}}$ the associated torus to the general  qudratic field $ \mathbb{Q} \sqrt d $?

Comment: if $d \in \mathbb{Z}_{< 0}$ then $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\sqrt{d}\mathbb{Z})$ is a complex torus (isomorphic as a Riemann surface and abelian group to a [complex elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#General_theory)) with [complex multiplication](http://planetmath.org/examplesofellipticcurveswithcomplexmultiplication) by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. Also about the LLT see [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_primalité_de_Lucas-Lehmer_pour_les_nombres_de_Mersenne#Preuve)

Comment: The  norm-1-torus is just the set of solutions of the Pell equation $x^2 - dy^2 = 4$. See http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-08/S0002-9939-2011-11196-1/S0002-9939-2011-11196-1.pdf.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer , I don't have access to this article. What is the **title** of this paper?

Comment: "GENERALIZED LUCAS-LEHMER TESTS USING PELL CONICS" by Sam Hambleton.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer , thank you in advance.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer 

What does it mean by: 

**It ($\varepsilon$) provides an integral point 
on the algebraic torus $T$ mentioned in the introduction.**
Could you explain the corresponding point to $\varepsilon$, **explicitly**?

Comment: @reuns What does it mean by: It (εε) provides an integral point on the algebraic torus TT mentioned in the introduction. Could you explain the corresponding point to εε, explicitly?

Comment: It means that $(2,1)$ is an integral point on the norm-1-torus $x^2 - 3y^2 = 1$. For tori over fields, it is irrelevant whether you look at $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$ or $x^2 - dy^2 = 4$. As for 2), the norm map on finite fields is always surjective by a standard counting argument,

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer , If by the **one-dimensional algebraic torus $T$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, associated to the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q} \sqrt3$** we mean "$\mathbb{C}/ (\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt3)$" as noted; then $\varepsilon=2+3 \sqrt3$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: @reuns , If by the **one-dimensional algebraic torus $T$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, associated to the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q} \sqrt3$** we mean "$\mathbb{C}/ (\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \sqrt3)$" as noted; then $\varepsilon=2+3 \sqrt3$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: I specified $d < 0$. Here $\sqrt{3}$ is different. That's why you need to read the paper to see what point on what curve and what group it is about exactly. Franz gave you some clues.

Comment: @reuns , yes you are right; you have been specified the condition, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T$ be the algebraic curve defined by $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$ over ${\mathbb Q}$,
where $d$ is a nonsquare. Over the quadratic extension $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{d})$, $T$ becomes isomorphic to $K^\times$, since 
$$ 1 = x^2 - dy^2 = (x - y\sqrt{d}) \cdot (x + y\sqrt{d}). $$
In fact, given any $t \in K^\times$ we have $\frac1t \in K^\times$ and $\frac1t \cdot t = 1$. Set $x = \frac12(t + \frac1t)$ and $y = \frac1{2\sqrt{d}}(t - \frac1t)$. Then the map $t \mapsto (x,y)$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups. This shows that, by definition, $T$ is a $1$-dimensional torus over the rationals since over $K$ we have $T \simeq K^\times$.

The point $(2,1)$ is an element of the torus for $d = 3$ since $2^2 - 3 \cdot 1^2 = 1$, and under the isomorphism above this element becomes $2 + \sqrt{3}$ when viewed over ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

The very same argument holds over any field in which $d$ is not a square, in particular over finite fields with $p$ elements with $(\frac dp) = -1$. If you then set $q = p^2$, the norm map $N: {\mathbb F}_q^\times \longrightarrow 
{\mathbb F}_p^\times$ is surjective. In fact, the generating automorphism is
the Frobenius maps, which raises everything to the $p$-th power, so the norm
in your quadratic extension is $N(x) = x^{p+1}$. Its kernel, the elements of
norm $1$, are the roots of the polynomial $x^{p+1} - 1$, and since we are working in a field, there are at most $p+1$ elements in the kernel. Thus the image of the norm has at least $p-1$ elements, and since ${\mathbb F}_p$ does have $p-1$ elements, we have equality.

If you replace the field with $p^2$ elements by a field with $p^3$ elements, then the elements of norm $1$ will give you a $2$-dimensional torus over ${\mathbb F}_p$.

Comment: With $K^\times$ you meant $\{ a \in K, N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a) = 1\}$

Comment: (with $p = 2^l-1$) the LLT [is based](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_primalit%C3%A9_de_Lucas-Lehmer_pour_les_nombres_de_Mersenne#Preuve) on $(2+\sqrt{3})^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv -1 \bmod p$. So we'll look at  the "semi-norm" map $ M(\alpha) = \alpha^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$. Now p.1-6 of [the paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gross/preprints/Mersenne.pdf) is a formulation of the LLT in your framework. But I don't follow part 2, about an elliptic curve.

Comment: p.9 the author uses the [Hasse bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves#Hasse-Weil_Bound) to deduce a deduction if $2^l-1$ is not prime and the point on the curve has order $2^l$.

Comment: @reuns: Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: If you are interested I wrote what I understand of the paper, and I can't make it a lot simpler.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer , You have been said that: **so the norm
in your quadratic extension is $N(x) = x^{p+1}$**; **How?**

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer , The norm map equal to $x^2-3y^2$? , am I right?

Answer (score 2):

In your [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gross/preprints/Mersenne.pdf) p.1-6 formulates the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_primalit%C3%A9_de_Lucas-Lehmer_pour_les_nombres_de_Mersenne#Preuve) in the words of Franz's answer. The elliptic curve part starts p.7. In short :

- Look at the elliptic curve $E : y^2=x^3-12x, (x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}$. With its group law define $[n](x,y)$, and also $[i](x,y)= (-x,iy)$ so $E$ has complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Also (with the Schoof algorithm ?) one can show $E$ is generated by two points $P= (-2,4)$ of infinite order and $Q = (0,0)$ of order $2$.
- Let $p = 2^l-1$, assume it is prime, and set $E(p) : y^2 = x^3-12x,  (x,y) \in \mathbb{F}_p$, still having CM by $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. The CM theory says $E(p) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[i]/(F-1)$ where $F = a+ib$ is equal to the Frobenius $(x,y) \mapsto (x^p,y^p)$, and $F^2 =-p$.
- Thus $-p = (F-1)^2-1+2(F-1)$ and $F-1$ is coprime with every prime $\ne 2$ and $E(p)$ is cyclic with $2^l$ elements with $P$ as generator.
- If $p$ is not prime and $ord(P) = 2^l$, then take $q$ the least prime factor of $2^l-1$, we still have $ord(P) = 2^l$ in $E(q)$. But (by the Hasse bound) this group has at most $q+1+2\sqrt{q} < 2^l$ points, a contradiction.

I'm not sure why you need to study it if you don't know the (CM) theory of elliptic curves, you should better start with Silverman's, the arithmetic of elliptic curves.